# Custom Deserializer using MongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, gson, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using SpringBoot, Spring Data and MongoRepository to store and retrieve objects.

When using MongoRepository, is there a way to provide a custom json deserializer (preferably a GSON , which can do some additional work instead of the internal deserializer)?

For example, i am calling:

```
Data data = repo.findOne(id); // where repo is a MongoRepository
```

I would like data to have some additional fields set in a custom manner (call them derived field values).  I can ofcourse set the derived fields directly on the data object above, but it would be cleaner if I can hook a deserializer at the time of retrieval.

For example, without spring data, i can use mongodb cursors and hook gson deserializers as below:

```
public List<Data> getData() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Data> dataRecords = new ArrayList<Data>();
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = db.getCollection("DataCollection").find().iterator();
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            dataRecords.add(gson.fromJson(JSON.serialize(cursor.next()), Data.class));
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return dataRecords;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way this can be done is
 1. The fields which you want to add (when the document is deserialized), declare those as `@Transient` in your entity `Data` class
 2. Put this on your Entity class `@AccessType(PROPERTY)`. This will ensure that your setter's are used to deserialize(By default it will not be). So your setters are called when it tries to deserialize(for non transient fields). You can call setter's for your transient fields from the non- transient fields.